# how to find the wrong parameters when use mybatis executortype.batch insert batch a time

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

my code simple like this:

```
@Autowired
private SqlSession sqlSession; //this sqlsession is figured with ExecutorType.BATCH
......
@transactional
public void batchInsert(List<T> entityList){
    BatchMapper batchMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(batchMapper.class);
    for(T entity:entityList){
        batchMapper.insert(entity)
    }
}
```

1000 entity insert a time, but when something wrong in one entity, how to find it? log level is info, I use try catch batchInsert method when I need use it, when exception throw, I log all 1000 entity, I want to konw is there any better idea to do it?

Comment: Your code isn't `@Transactional(executorType=ExecutorType.BATCH)` so I don't think it's a batch statement, just a regular transaction (Unless you're using a custom annotation)  If you are using the standard `@Transactional` batch, it will give you an error like `Update statement #13 was rolled back` in your log.  That should help you figure out which one is the culprit.

Comment: @kendavidson ORM in my project is mybatis, sqlsession is figured with ExecutorType.BATCH, I think this is mybatis feature.

Comment: Regardless, you should still see either (1) `statement #X was rolled back` if there was a failure or (2) the full listing of insert/update parameters in the logs.  My initial comment assumed an error, but if just referring to data, the parameters are shown.